# Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).connect is not a function at connect (index.js:47532) at Object.connect (

Tags: reactjs, rabbitmq, rpc

I am getting this error

[image: Img]

when I am trying to test  code on react project:

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');


export function start2 (conn) {

console.log("hello")

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost:8000', function (err, conn) {

    conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
        var q = 'frontend';
        var msg = 'Hello!';

        ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});
        // Note: on Node 6 Buffer.from(msg) should be used
        ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(msg));
        console.log(" [x] Sent %s", msg);
    });
    setTimeout(function() { conn.close(); process.exit(0) }, 500);



});

}
```

any help please and thanks.

Comment: You can't use server-side code, like `amqplib`, in a browser.

Comment: thank you :)                                                                                                  
so, what can i do to send my message  on react project ???

Comment: Your React frontend has to send a message to your server (for instance, using [`socket.io`](https://socket.io/) and your server has to forward that message to RabbitMQ.

Comment: did you mean i should use socket.io to send a message from reactJs server (node)  to rabbitMq ?

Comment: You'd use `socket.io` to communicate between the browser and the Node server, and `amqplib` to communicate between the Node server and RabbitMQ (and vice versa). Your server has to act as a necessary go-between because the browser cannot communicate with RabbitMQ directly.

Comment: I will try it, thank you

Comment: @robertklep is there an way that I can communicate directly to rabbitmq from react

Comment: @Tushar never tried myself, but [look here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html).