# Rabbit-MQ with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rabbitmq

Does React work with Rabbit-MQ? I've been googling myself to death the past few days and I could only find results regarding React Native.

Can I just follow a Javascript-RabbitMQ-Tutorial or is there something specific?

I'm thankful for any hint.

Comment: Isn't RabbitMQ a message queuing system? I know not much about it, but sounds very backend to me; When it's coupled with Javascript in a tutorial, I'd guess they mean Node.js.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it is a message queueing system. I actually found [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html) on their homepage. Not sure if there's a better convention, so that's why I asked.

Comment: It depends on what are you trying to achieve. Basically you can make work React with RabbitMQ client, but in most cases it isn't the right solution. If you want to add real-time features to your app you better look at websocket solutions like https://github.com/socketio/engine.io

Comment: @MikhailZhuravlev - I am trying to implement a GUI that updates based on certain inventory changes through a service in the backend.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Here is an example of RPC support for RabbitMQ http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-javascript.html
- RabbitMQ provides has plugins which enables to connect to the server via websockets. 
  http://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html 
  Samples are here https://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html#web-messaging
- There are couple of nodejs client libraries too. It is worth to take a look at them if you are using webpack. May be they will just work in the browser.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into the links!

Comment: So, I've found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936495/uncaught-typeerror-webpack-require-connect-is-not-a-function-at-connec) and @robertklep explains how it's done but it's way too abstract. I've already setup the consumer and read the article about web-stomp but I'm lost tbh. Any suggestions?

My project is just a simple React app. My backend is a spring boot service that already has a sender, which works.

Comment: He is telling the same "Use websocket"

Comment: So do you mean like `[backend_service] -> [RabbitMQ] ->`[RabbitMQ-Web-Stomp](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/05/14/introducing-rabbitmq-web-stomp/) -> ReactApp - I'm sorry, the question may seem stupid but I just can't picture the hierarchy.

Comment: RabbitMQ server -> backend websocket server -> react client (connect to websocket)

Comment: I made implementation but I have a problem to reading a value in Redux store. On the onMessageArrived, the  tablist's value is the initial state in Redux store.  How can I solve this issue?

In react hooks, I use like this. 
 const tabList = useAppSelector(selectTabs);

Answer (score 2):

I also had difficulties in implementing Rabbit MQ in React js.

But one of my friends **enabled/install mqtt and websocket** plugins in our Rabbit Mq server.

So now I can communicate our React js app with Rabbit MQ using simple mqtt or websocket.

Answer (score 1):

I required this for one of my projects and ended up going with this approach

FE -> BACKEND SERVICE -> RABBITMQ

Basically, the backend service is responsible for listening to the rabbitmq, and has the responsibility of receiving and publishing messages to the Queue cluster.
I used the library;
https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib
I believe this is the most used library for RabbitMq Connectivity (via amqp) considering the weekly downloads on the npmjs website. I strongly recommend you to use a stable library especially if you are new to rabbitmq and this nature of work.
This is in addition to the answer given by @Arun Karunagath above.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rabbitode you can try this library provides a nice abstraction of the amqplib package from nodejs