# How to use RabitMQ client integrate with React js (without server api like nodejs,.net) ? Publish message using react js straightly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, frontend

Dec: I want to use RabitMQ without nodejs or other API. How to use straightly in react js?

Reference link: 
Stack Overflow similar soultion: (but with node js and socket io)
[Rabbit-MQ with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48741704/rabbit-mq-with-react)

RabitMQ Solution for client:
https://cloudamqp.github.io/amqp-client.js/

RabitMQ Solution for javascript (node js):
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html