# Not able to connect rabbitMQ in ReactJs, using amqplib library

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rabbitmq

```
amqpLibTest(){
 alert("connection Started")
 let amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
 debugger
 amqp.connect('amqp://myuser:notapassword@123.123.123.xyz.com:5672', 
  function(err, conn) {
  console.log("Conn Values=======>", conn)
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
  let q = 'harbinger-dm-control-response';

ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: true});
console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q);
ch.consume(q, function(msg) {
let js = JSON.parse(msg.content.toString());
console.log(js);
 }, {noAck: true});
});
});
}
```

I am trying to connect to rabbitmq service which is running on another server. It is giving me below ERRORs:
[Error of my Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxUYg.png)

The Error in browser console is:-

> Uncaught TypeError: **webpack_require**(...).connect is not a function
>       at connect (connect.js:169)
>       at Object.connect (callback_api.js:14)
>       at App.amqpLibTest (App.js:54)
>       at new App (App.js:44)
>       at constructClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:11447)
>       at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13144)

Comment: Apparently this is the reason, but I have not seen a solution yet :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936495/uncaught-typeerror-webpack-require-connect-is-not-a-function-at-connec